# How to fix '"Character/_input does not exist in the current context" in Antlr with C# as target language?

Tags: java, c#, .net-core, antlr

I have successfully generated parser and lexer using Antlr4 with target language c#.
Used Grammar file is for Java 9. Link to the grammar file is here  [Java9.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/java9/Java9.g4)

[image]

In the generated .cs files, Java9Lexer.cs is throwing the below errors when tried to compile in dotnet core project.

```
     error CS0103: The name 'Character' does not exist in the current context 
     error CS0103: The name '_input' does not exist in the current context
```

Please help me fix this error the right way! :) Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: The Java9.g4 grammar is written with the assumption that you are targeting Java. Java is used in the action blocks so as is it is not target independent. I rewrote this for C# at https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/Java.

Comment: I just now saw your comment @kaby76. Why not create an answer instead?

Comment: @BartKiers I will never create "answers". I give my "opinion" so people can take it or leave it, forces the comment to a few hundred characters, and cannot be edited after 5 minutes. I have been slammed too many times over very minor stuff. I've been programming compilers for 35+ years, yet everybody--even a high school kid--is far superior in writing software.

Comment: Fair enough @kaby76!

Comment: Thank You @kaby76 for the inputs. I will check it out. Congrats to you for the 35+ years in compiler programming. That's great.

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside `{` and `}?` in `.g4` files is target specific code. In your case, it's Java code. Since you're targeting C#, you need to replace that Java code with the C# equivalent.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Will make necessary changes.